# Why does model become too large after adding modifiers?

Tags: subdivision-surface, mirror

[image]

I started to make a human model with a tutorial followed it exactly... added a plane then merged the vertices extruded it added mirror modifier then skin modifier and added subdivision surface modifier over it in this order with render and viewport value 3. what happened was.... the model became too large... even after zooming out it was not in the screen... but when I reduce the value in subdivision mod to 2. the skin disappears. plz guide.
I am an absolute beginner... so I am having trouble without doing much work.

i have uploaded the file on blender exchange
[image]

Comment: well the mesh looks normal to me

Comment: Fine here too! Displays as a 'T' shape which is currently just under 4 metres tall on the Z axis in Object mode..

Comment: can u plz try n change the values in subdivision modifier and see.... as i change values there it becomes too large or its just T without skin

Comment: Still fine increasing the viewport level right up to 6 with no visible changes apart from smoothness. Levels of 2 or 3 are the normal levels to use when modelling with the skin modifier. What tutorial are you following? - Joey Carlino has several detailed modelling tutorials using that system, for instance [this one](https://youtu.be/DAAwy_l4jw4).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLyJWE02WfQ&list=PLUh4uxLfg-RLkYq17GFbeMIr5kEsTdrOZ&index=13

Comment: i am using above mention tutorial... i got another problem previously... i made a conveyor belt using some other tutorial and despite i applied all rigid body  things as in tutorial my things were just flying around...

Comment: but as u can see.. in the screenshot my T goes too big... when get to 3... when i reduce hte value it just vanish with only vertices left...

Comment: I don't speak Hindi, but just watching and following the first part of that video gives me exactly the same result as he shows in the video and the file you uploaded is fine too so I've no idea what is causing problems in your case. The conveyor belt problem you mention should be a separate question. Have you tried reinstalling Blender just in case there's a problem with it?

Comment: yeah i did... reinstalled it again....Alright... thankx alooot for all the help... thankyou again....